# Operator precedence for And and Or

Tags: ruby

Lets say I have the following line of code: `return nil unless app && ip || device`

Without parenthesis, how will Ruby interpret the precedence? `(app && ip) || device`? or `app && (ip || device)`?

Or some other way?

Thanks!

Comment: @nietonfir did you read both questions? They are completely different.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence

Comment: @MarekLipka I fail to see how that Wikipedia page is relevant to the question. In fact, it is quite misleading, since in Ruby, there's the special case of `and` which has lower precedence than `&&` and `||`.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt this question is about precedence between `&&` and `||`, not between `&&` and `and`. And in this scope Ruby meet expectations from mathematical logical operators - `&&` has precedence over `||` (and, accordingly, `and` has precedence over `or`) .

Comment: @MarekLipka That's true, but I still consider it misleading in this context, since Ruby has the specialty of lower-precedence variants of these operators. But YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple - since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, it will be interpreted as

```
  (app && ip) || device
```

I'd recommend to always add the parentheses for readability purposes, though.

See e.g. [Rosettacode page on operator precedence for Ruby](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Operator_precedence#Ruby)